# git : clone doesn't bring all the files?

Tags: git, ssh

I did all this steps and at the end I clone my respo, but unfortunaly, 
I don't have every files in the server ?

```
etape 1
// in server
mkdir hub-plugins
cd hub-plugins
// initialise git sans repertoire de travail "working directory"
git init --bare

etape 2
in local
// add 
git remote add origin ssh://root@IP/home/web/xavier-artot.com/ftp/www/hub-plugins
// on ajoute .git local qu server
git push origin master

etape 3
in server
// I clone the test
git clone hub-plugins test
```

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be running git init and git clone in the same directory.  You should run git init on the server, then git clone on your local machine to create a new instance of your repository.  From here, you make changes, commit them, and push them to your server.

Comment: I don't undestand ?

menu_css3 git:(master) cd..

git clone menu_css3 to the server ?

Thanks

Comment: You created the git repo on the server.  It is there.  If you ran git clone on your local machine, it should copy all of your files from the server to your local machine, assuming your references are set up appropriately.